# SimpleDateFormatter "ddMMyyyy" incorrectly parse month and year

Tags: java, datetime

I'm parsing user date of birth string. And faced a very strange parsing scenario.

My code is the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy")
try {
  Date date = formatter.parse(input); // input - is a user entered string
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

If `input` is "2222**1985**", I have a date 22, October, **1986**. But I expect some sort of ParseException for this and similar scenario, when month is higher, then 12.

Comment: There will be no parse exceptions because this is how Calendar works in Java.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You will want `LocalDate.parse("22221985", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMuuuu").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT))`. It throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '22221985' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 22`. And enjoy how precise and informative the exception message is.